# What should be the right dhcp configuration for generating a new network over eth0?

Tags: networking, ip, networkmanager, dhcp

Even not under a real server like scenario, I'm testing with **`dhcpd`** for learning and practice purposes. I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

I want to *offer* a network by my **`eth0`** interface. I receive ip and so internet by **`wlan0`**.

These are the ip adresses:

**`192.168.0.1`** is my home router.
**`192.168.19.6`** is my wlan0 ip. (Assigned by MAC adress)
**`192.168.0.196`** is my eth0 ip. (Assigned by MAC adress case I plug in to the router)
So, as it might be assumed, my home router dhcp mask is **`255.255.0.0`**.

I want to test it at first with my raspberry. So over my eth0 bears a new network, and it or *they*  (case I plug a switch) get ip adresses from my dhcp server.

This is what I've set for **`/etc/network/interface`** file:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
       address 192.168.0.196
       netmask 255.255.255.0
       gateway 192.168.0.196
```

This is what I've set for **`/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf`** file:

```
option domain-name-servers 8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4;

subnet  192.168.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0{
   option routers 192.168.0.196;
   range  192.168.0.10  192.168.0.120;
}
```

And I looked for a way to make my clients get access to internet, found this:

```
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -o wlan0 -i eth0 -s 192.168.0.0/24 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -t nat -F POSTROUTING
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wlan0 -j MASQUERADE
```

However, when I get *networking* and *network-manager* services restarted with that configuration I'm losing my wlan0 connection and not even my clients get ip not even way out to internet.

I simply want to receive and consume connection by wlan0, generate a new network over eth0 and share my wlan0 internet through it. What's wrong in my configuration?